# Is there a way to use rand() with a variable?

Tags: c

I want to use rand in a loop with an int variable which decrements during each loop.

Can I do something like

```
randomNumber = rand()%d, otherIntVar;
```

?

EDIT: Everyone, you can just put the name of an integer variable there instead of a number and it will work.

Comment: Where `randomNumber = rand()%d, otherIntVar;` means? because it's valid syntax, but it discards `radn() % d`

Comment: I would like the range of numbers that are randomly chosen from to be 0-otherIntVar.

Comment: What do you think the `%` is doing?

Comment: Well I know I can go randNum = rand()%7 and that will give me a random number in the range of 0-6. What does it do?

Comment: What exactly is your question @user3169700? You want to know how the % operator works? Or do you want to know how to limit what random values to obtain through rand()? Please be clear.

Comment: Sorry. I know how to limit the random values obtained through rand. What I want is to have the limit of values be a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ITERATION_COUNT   10 // define your loop count here
#define INIT_VALUE       100 // define your initial value here

int main()
{
   int i, num, val;

   val = INIT_VALUE;

   for(i = 0; i<ITERATION_COUNT; ++i)
   {
       num = rand() % val;  // yields a random number between [0-val]
       --val;               // define how much it needs to be decremented

       // your program logic
   }

   // your program logic

   return 0;
}
```

However, you should add your control logic properly otherwise you will not get the results as you predicted. (Set your iteration count and decremential rate proportional to eachother for example.)

Comment: Thank you. I actually didn't understand that you could go num = rand()% val;

I thought you needed to put an actual number there. My question was how to replace, say, 7, with "val."

Comment: Basically, it produces a random number between 0 and the value of val variable. Then it decrements value of val in each iteration and this time it yields a random number between 0 and [val-1] (it decrements the value of val by one in the code above, if you want a different decremential, define it by yourself)

Comment: ok, now I understand you're a newbie to C. You can put variables or constants to arithmetic operations as the same way. For example: int result, mod = 3; result = 10 % mod;  and result = 10 % 3; will totally give you the same result. You're welcome, glad to help. And next time, please be more specific and declarative while asking your question. Keep learning :)